# How to install new units (i mean includes ex: stdio.h) for my C

Tags: c, download, installation, include

How to install new units (i mean includes ex: stdio.h) for my C, and how to download more?

Comment: stdio.h comes by default in any proper C compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put the header file on the same folder as your main source file,
ex:

> /folder /-->main.c
>
> ```
>     -->function.h
>     -->function.c
> ```

then on main.c include it by writing :

```
  #include "function.h"
```

the quotes are used to include a header file that's on the same folder as your c source file
u can also write your own and include them like above.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for libraries. The headers (normally) just contain information to tell the compiler about the content of the library. There are quite a few [C libraries](http://sourceforge.net/search/?type_of_search=soft&words=C+library) to be found, covering all sorts of different topics. Of course, SourceForge isn't the only place to look -- Github and Google code would be a couple more obvious ones.